# Failed to save question1Controller.js: ESLINT_ERROR: {c:question1 - CONTROLLER} line:col [20:9] --> Parsing error: Unexpected token else : Source

Tags: lightning

**design file**

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="questionText" label="Question Text"
                      description="Provide the question text here." />
    <design:attribute name="answers" label="Possible Answers"
                      description="Provide the potential answers (yes:true,no:false for example) here." />
</design:component>
```

**Controller file**

```
({  

    handleAnswer : function(component, event, helper) {
        var validity = helper.handleAnswer(event);
        action.setParams({
            "validity" : event.getSource().get("v.value"),
            "selectedQuestion" : component.get("v.Question")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if ( validity == 'true' )
                var sMsg = 'Valid';                
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                mode: 'dismissible',
                duration:' 5000',
                message: sMsg,
                type : 'success'
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
        else if ( validity == 'false' );
        var errors = response.getError();
        if (errors) {
            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                var sMsg = errors[0].message;                
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    mode: 'dismissible',
                    duration:' 5000',
                    message: sMsg,
                    type : 'error'
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        }
        else
            component.set("v.message", 'Invalid' );
    }
}
});
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    alert('something went wrong ' + validity);
}

})
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAnswers(component);
    },
```

**Helper**

```
    ({
    getAnswers : function(component) {
        var answersList  = component.get("v.answers");
        var answerObjects    =             [];
        answersList  = answersList.split(',');


        for (var i = 0; i < answersList.length; i++){
            var answers = answersList[i].split(':');
            var answerObject = {answerLabel:answers[0], answerValidity:answers[1]};
            answerObjects.push(answerObject);
            console.log(i + ' answer is ' + answers[0] + ' validity is ' + answers[1]);
        }
        component.set('v.answerObjects', answerObjects);
        console.log(answerObjects);
    },

    handleAnswer : function(event) {
        var validity = event.getSource().get("v.value").trim().toLowerCase();
        console.log(validity);
        return validity;
    }
})
```

Comment: You will find your work *dramatically* easier if you (1) always use curly braces around every single block (including `if`/`else`), and (2) utilize a JavaScript formatter to indent your code correctly. This is a pretty simple syntax error stemming from a missing bracket.

Comment: Jeff, I don't see an actual question. Please take the time to read [ask]. Thanks

Comment: @DavidReed which `JavaScript formatter` does a Ninja like you recommend?

Comment: @Robs I am emphatically not a JavaScript ninja - my JS is workmanlike at best - but I've had success with the built-in format support in Visual Studio Code. Perhaps someone with more front-end experience can speak to the toolchain!

Comment: @DavidReed I use the builtin one too. Was just curious.

Answer (score 2):

You have several important syntax errors, and I'm not going to go through and correct the code line-by-line but simply point out the *classes* of issues here and how to start correcting them.

At

```
        if ( validity == 'true' )
```

you are missing an open bracket for this block. You should make a point of *always* bracketing your blocks. It is far too easy to make mistakes about the scope of a conditional, since it's legal to place a single statement after a conditional without braces.

You are similarly missing a bracket, and have an extra semicolon, at

```
    else if ( validity == 'false' );
```

While it is syntactically valid, you should use braces at

```
    else
        component.set("v.message", 'Invalid' );
```

As a consequence of these issues and your issues with indenting, which may stem from poor brace structure, your closing brackets and parenthesis for the callback, call to `$A.enqueueAction`, and controller function are disordered and need to be checked when you correct your other issues.